# Noise in high frequency photodiode op-amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, photodiode

I am trying to use an [op amplifier](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ada4817-1_4817-2.pdf) for my [photodiode](https://www.thorlabs.com/thorproduct.cfm?partnumber=FDS100) using this scheme:
[image]

The expected amplification is 5, ut instead I am getting a nearly constant output independent of light on photodiode.

I tried to directly put a100 kHz 1V sine signal instead of the photodiode into the op-amp, but the oscilloscope shows a lot of extra noise with output signal.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For a 1GHz opamp you have to show your layout. Also why not use it as transimpedance amplifier?

Comment: Seems a bare-bones schematic, missing power supply bypass capacitors. And what is done with **power-down** pin?

Comment: @bobflux - If you've got the optical power, this setup gives you maximum speed. After all, the point of the normally-required feedback cap is to slow the circuit down so that it doesn't oscillate.

Comment: @glen_geek I connected PD to +5V also as it was said in datashit

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this requires a good deal more information. To begin with, what sort of signal are you looking at? Your present geometry is normally used for monitoring very fast pulses with a lot of light available. The low detection impedance takes a lot of energy to produce a useable pulse. The fact that you're using a gain of 9 suggests that this is what you are doing.

For a very fast op amp, such as the one you're using, layout and decoupling are critical. The evaluation board https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/user-guides/8-Lead_LFCSP_Amplifer_UG-919.pdf should give you an idea of what you need. Note the multiple decoupling capacitors and pc board layers. In a lot of ways, especially if you only need a single channel you're better off just buying an evaluation board.

I presume (but I might be wrong, which is why I bring it up) that you've already tried a version of the circuit with just the photodiode and the 50-ohm resistor, and verified that your input to the op amp is behaving as you expect. If you've got hum pickup or stray light, that can produce the results you see.